# Copper loss of a synchronous motor at a particular load

Tags: motor, ac, efficiency, synchronous-motor

Imagine I'm driving a 50KW synchronous motor of full load current of 10A as a generator using a motor. Assume the driving motor losses to be negligible.
Am I right about the following statements?

When the excitation of the synchronous machine is off, the driving motor consumes 500W, which is equal to the mechanical loss in the synchronous machine.

With the armature terminals short circuited and with an armature current of 10A the driving motor takes 2000W, which means sum of mechanical loss and full load copper loss is 2000W implying full load copper loss is 1500W.

With excitation on and armature open circuited, the driving motor consumes 1500W, which means sum of mechanical and iron loss is 1500W implying iron loss is 1000W.

Now the efficiency of the synchronous motor at 50% of load is

Load = 25KW

Mechanical loss = 500W

Iron loss = 1000W

Copper loss = (Fraction of the load squared) * Full load copper loss = 0.25 * 1500 = 375W

Efficiency = 25000/(25000+500+1000+375)

My concern is that, was I right in estimating half load copper loss from full load copper loss?

PS: Numerical values discussed are only hypothetical, not experimental.

Comment: The 500 watt statement is unfounded on any theory that I know of. I stopped reading at that point.

Comment: Its actually a question asked for the common entrance examination for various universities in India

Comment: If you feel so, may be its right, I don't know, my concern is about estimating half load copper loss from given full load copper loss, that's all.

Comment: But how did you conclude that 500 watts is the mechanical loss?

Comment: Assuming the driving motor to  be loss less, any power drawn by it should be transferred to the load attached to it, here its the rotating part of the synchronous machine, which has frictional losses, such as bearing loss, wind friction loss, etc.

Comment: I think that you are correct provided that the excitation is adjusted for unity power factor.

Comment: @ARJUNCVENU But how can you justify the value 500 watts?

Comment: @Andyaka You mean how "500W"? Its a fictional value. I only wanted to know my method of approach is correct.

Comment: @CharlesCowie Could you tell me how excitation affects my question, or at-least tell me what should I search in google to find relevant details?

Comment: @ARJUNCVENU then you cannot justify it. You said *"Am I right about the following statements?"* - then, in the first following statement you mentioned 500 watts - so how can you be right about it without some unseen knowledge or justification?

Comment: The 500 watts determined by driving the machine includes all losses of the driving machines and assumes that speed is the rated speed of the driven machine. To determine the losses that way, it is necessary to be able to calculate the losses of the driving machine at the power level of the driven machine mechanical losses and subtract the driving machine losses.

Comment: My first sentence says "Imagine...."
one can't expect examinations to ask questions with correct experimental data?

Comment: @CharlesCowie Exactly, for the sake of simplicity, the losses on driving machine is assumed to be zero,of course a hypothetical condition.

Comment: You need to look at synchronous machine "V curve." Also, I am not sure that I have interpreted all of the points in the question correctly.

Comment: If the efficiency of the driving machine is assumed to be 100% or sufficiently high for an accurate answer, that assumption should be stated and justified in the answer to the question.

Comment: The question has generated a discussion rather than an answer. That seems the only response possible. I voted to close the question.

Comment: How did you get Fe loss at 100W?

Comment: Its typo, meant to say 1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your estimation of the copper (ohmic) loss. It depends only on the current.

What can be wrong is the implied assumption that both the mechanical loss and the iron (hysteresis) loss are indepedent of the load. This is not necessarily true, but I think there is no enough data to go deeper.

Comment: I agree on the mechanical loss/iron loss being not independent on the load, it was actually an oversimplification done commonly when asking numerical questions.